# wmd text editor executes the code

Tags: javascript, html, wmd-editor

I am using WMD text-editor in my website as

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="wmd-master/wmd.css" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="wmd-master/showdown.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/index2.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

But whenever I put a code in WMD editor, the code gets executed. How can I stop this?

for example:

[image]

It can be seen in the demo of WMD editor as well. [WMD DEMO](http://ephemera.continuation.org/stackoverflow/wmd/wmd-test.html)
Thanks in advance.

Comment: no different than the one here...you need to wrap code in code blocks

Comment: @charlietfl Sorry, I didn't get it.

Comment: use back ticks to wrap code or use an html editor instead of a markdown editor

Comment: How does stackoverflow tackle this situation because I guess they also use the same text-editor